# Let X be a Compact metric space and $F\subset C(X)$ be a compact subset. Show that F is equicontinuous.

Tags: real-analysis, compactness, equicontinuity

Let $X$ be a compact metric space and $F\subset C(X)$ be a compact subset. Show that $F$ is equicontinuous.

*Proof:* Let $f\in F$ be an arbitrary function. I want to show that $\forall \epsilon>0, \exists\,\delta>0$ such that, if $|x-y|<\delta$ then $|f(x)-f(y)|< \epsilon \ $ for all $f\in F$ and $\forall x,y\in X$.

I'm stuck in here. Should I take a sequence of functions?
How do I use the compactness of $X$ and compactness of $F$.

Comment: What is $\varepsilon$?

Comment: I just edited, $\epsilon >0$ I wrote the definition of the equicontnuity

Comment: [These old notes](http://at.yorku.ca/p/a/c/a/23.pdf) might help you on your way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $F$ is compact, for given $\epsilon > 0$ there exist $f_i \in F$ such that $F \subseteq \cup_{i=1}^nB(f_i, \frac{\epsilon}{3})$. Choose $\delta_i>0$ by the uniform continuity of $f_i$ for  $\frac{\epsilon}{3}$ and let $\delta$ be the minimum of $\delta_i$'s. Let $f \in F$ be arbitrary, then $f \in B(f_j, \frac{\epsilon}{3})$ for some $f_j$ thus $|f(x)-f_j(x)|< \frac{\epsilon}{3}$ for any $x$ , now $d(x_1,x_2)<\delta$ implies
\begin{align}
&|f(x_1)-f(x_2)| \leq |f(x_1)-f_j(x_1)|+|f_j(x_1)-f_j(x_2)|+|f_j(x_2)-f(x_2)|< \frac{\epsilon}{3}+\frac{\epsilon}{3}+\frac{\epsilon}{3}=\epsilon.
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you. That explains well.

Answer (score 1):

The standard way to do this is to use that a compact subset of a metric space $M$ is totally bounded, i.e. for every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a finite collection of open balls in $M$ of radius $\epsilon$ whose union contains $M$.

For given $\epsilon > 0$, you can take a finite collection of open balls of radius $\epsilon/3$ that cover $F$. It then becomes an $\epsilon/3$-style argument.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong. What I understand from your proof is ,by the compactness of F there are finite balls that covers F. so we can write $$|f(x-f(y))| <|f(x)|+|f(y)| <sup|f(x)|+sup|f(y)|<\epsilon$$ if we choose the $\delta= min{\delta_1,\delta_2...}$

Comment: Not quite. You can look at the proof of @absolute0 above. 

$|f(x) - f(y)| \leq |f(x) - f_n(x)| + |f_n(x) - f_n(y)| + |f_n(y) - f(y)| \leq d(f,f_n) + |f_n(x) - f_n(y)| + d(f_n,f)$

where $f \in f_n$. The second term is estimated by uniform continuity of the $f_n$. You can take $\delta$ to be the minimum of all their delta's.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you