# let $F\subset C(X)$ where C(X) are continuous functions on the compact interval $X$. Show that F is equicontinuous

Tags: real-analysis, compactness, equicontinuity

X be a compact metric space and let $F\subset C(X)$ where C(X) are continuous functions on the compact interval $X$. Show that F is equicontinuous. Here $F$ is compact

My work-

let me take a covering for $F$ such that for all $\epsilon>0$ and $F\subset \cup B(f_n,\frac{\epsilon}{3})$. Since $F$ is compact, there exists a finite covering such that $F\subset \cup_{n=1}^{n=N}B(f_n,\frac{\epsilon}{3})$.

Now let $f\in F$ then it should belong to some $B(f_n,\epsilon)$. that implies $sup|f-f_n|<\frac{\epsilon}{3}$.

Now let $x,y\in X$, consider $|f(x)-f(y)|=|f(x)-f_n(x)+f_n(x)-f_n(y)+f_n(y)-f(y)|\leq|f(x)-f_n(x)|+|f_n(x)-f_n(y)|+|f_n(y)-f(y)|$

$\leq \frac{\epsilon}{3}+|f_n(x)-f_n(y)|+\frac{\epsilon}{3}$

since, $f_n$ is uniformly continuous, (because  $f_n$ is continous on compact set)

for $\frac{\epsilon}{3}>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that if $|x-y|<\delta$ then $|f_n(x)-f_n(y)|<\frac{\epsilon}{3}$ for all $x,y\in X$.

hence, we can write,

$|f(x)-f(y)|=|f(x)-f_n(x)+f_n(x)-f_n(y)+f_n(y)-f(y)|\leq|f(x)-f_n(x)|+|f_n(x)-f_n(y)|+|f_n(y)-f(y)|$

$\leq \frac{\epsilon}{3}+\frac{\epsilon}{3}+\frac{\epsilon}{3}=\epsilon$

Therefore, for all $\epsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that if $|x-y|<\delta$ then $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$ for all $x,y\in X$.

Is this a correct proof? than you in advance.

Comment: I guess there is a typo. Don't you want to assume compactness for $F$?

Comment: As stated, the question  is wrong. Please check your source again.

Comment: Yes. I'm sorry for the typo. F is compact.

Comment: this has answers here  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4082157/let-x-be-a-compact-metric-space-and-f-subset-cx-be-a-compact-subset-show-th/4082492#4082492